# Why overflow didn't happen in here

Tags: binary, discrete-mathematics

In my past paper answer sheet there is an answer given below:

```
123 = 01111011
-65 = 10111111
sum = 00111010
Carry occurs, but can be ignored. No overflow, the sum is correct sign.
```

What is the meaning of "*the sum is correct sign*?" Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sum is correct sign** means that the msbit (in the 128's column) being `0` properly represents that the sum is positive.

**No overflow** means that the sum of `00111010` (58 decimal) can be represented in 8 bits.

**Carry occurs, but can be ignored** refers to the fact that the carry-in to the msbit occurs and matches the carry-out from the msbit, resulting in no overflow (and so can be ignored).  When the carry-in to the msbit does not match the carry-out from the msbit, there is signed overflow.

Comment: is 8t bit means MSB or LSB?

Comment: MSB.  Added "(in the 128's column)" to clarify.  Thanks.

Comment: I know it is avoid to say thanks. But still thanks once again. This is very important to me.